# Apptentive Library - How to edit it's source code

Tags: android, gradle, aar, apptentive

I am using Apptentive `.aar` library in my project and I have to make changes in its `values.xml` file. How to achieve it. Any help should be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple.
Since you have the source, just **overwrite the values** in your project using the same **id.**

For example if you want to change a [string](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android/blob/master/apptentive/res/values/strings.xml) just overwrite it in your `strings.xml`.

```
 <string name="apptentive_ok">XXX</string>
```

If you want to change a [color](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android/blob/master/apptentive/res/values/colors.xml), overwrite it in your `colors.xml`

```
<color name="colorPrimary">XXXXX</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Apptentive Android](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-android) Github Repository and,

1. Clone the project
2. Change it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the class where the value.xml is referenced is not protected or final, you could extend it in your project and point to your own value.xml file where needed.